# Protractor config for Angular2+ e2e that works both for local run & in docker

Tags: angular, docker, protractor, e2e

Recently I spent quite a time to start e2e test to my project and incorporate it into build pipeline. A setup requires at least 2 nodes (mongodb + .Net5 backend with Angular client) so it is been decided to run all of this in docker. I've added additional docker-compose-test.yml where I'll start temporary nodes to run server integration tests (that needs mongo) and then client tests including e2e (that needs completely working setup). So after days of tuning all of this I ended up with a `protractor.conf.js` that have a chromeDriver hardcoded for docker:

```js
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox'],
    },
  },
  directConnect: true,
  chromeDriver: '/usr/bin/chromedriver', // !!!
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4444/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
```

It finally works in docker perfectly (with chromedriver update disabled, since it is preinstalled on another stage into Alpine image, where automatic update not working at all otherwise, and it is just noticeable faster). But the problem is, not surprisingly, it is no longer works locally:
`Error message: Could not find chromedriver at Q:\usr\bin\chromedriver. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.`
Also additionally I always have to pass `--dev-server-target=` both locally and in docker because I'm always have this either already running in docker or in my local ng serve, so another dev-server don't make sense for me. I've added this to `package.json`: `"e2e": "ng e2e --dev-server-target="` it works for `npm run e2e`, but I also want to have `ng e2e` without parameters for local run (I believe it is possible to configure, but how?)

And how I can setup chromedriver that works both in docker and on a local runs?

Local runs are easier to debug and faster to start...

NOTE: `4444` is a port of my dev web server, I just recently realized that selenium uses the same.

Comment: Why do you need exactly the same config in both? Add a Selenium [standalone image](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome) into the Docker compose network and point Protractor to it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not sure I fully understand (just started learning this area) but if I got it right, I'm not actually using selenium host because of directConnect=true, don't I? So my protractor pointed directly to the web host. Are you suggesting to set directConnect=false and use selenium?

Comment: When you use directConnect you have to have the browser and driver running on the same host. It makes sense for your local run, but in the container network it makes the test container more complicated so it's easier to just add the standalone container into the network and point Protractor to it.

Comment: In fact you can see how I've done it in https://github.com/textbook/react-ts-fe/tree/4e56934420fe3470469795bed5664c27016ac43e/e2e - it uses WebdriverIO rather than Protractor, but the ideas of externalising the config to env vars so it can be adapted to different environments and using a standalone Selenium image in a Docker compose network are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I did in this case was to declare a docker image specific environment variable

```
# Dockerfile
ENV DOCKERIMAGEENV="true"
```

and then inside the config, I placed a simple if/else logic

```
if (process.env.DOCKERIMAGEENV) {
  // do whatever you need for your docker
} else {
  // local specific options
}
```

so in your case this would look like this

```
let chromedriverPath;

if (process.env.DOCKERIMAGEENV) {
  chromedriverPath = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
} else {
  chromedriverPath = 'C:\another\path'
}

exports.config =  {
  directConnect: true,
  chromeDriver: chromedriverPath,
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I'm looking for!